# Why my finally() block is not working i.e if the test case fails finally block is also not executed in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to do this inside it function.

````
      try {
      console.log("Here I am using the data created in db")
      } finally {
      console.log("Here I am trying to delete the created data in db")
      }```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want catch the error, you must add `catch(){}` to catch the Exception.
Here is an example:

```
try {
    // try to execute this statements...
}catch( Exception e ) {
    // if a more general exception was thrown, handle it here
}
finally {
    // here you can clean things up afterwards
}`
```

Comment: Thanks I thought that I don't need to catch the error so i didn't use it.Myrequirement is just even if test case fails my finally block should run. I will try using catch .